# Trying to execute PHP from JavaScript, not working?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using the following code: `<a href="#" onclick="<?php var_dump($_SERVER)?>">$_SERVER Variable</a>`. is this even possible? if not then how would I do this? I amn using $_SERVER for very specific - experimental purposes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, see [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: Can I see a simple example that will get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can always send AJAX requests to a php file on the server and parse the response back into your HTML/JS. Check out jQuery's AJAX if you want the easy route ;)  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
 A much easier example found at: 
Sorry, for the self promotion, but on [jQuery's Ajax Tutorial](http://afterhoursprogramming.com/index.php?content=JavaScript-jQuery-With-AJAX&article=84) I cover this :)

Comment: ok, but I repeat: Can you please show me something that will get this to work as I am experienced in PHP but I am far from experienced in JavaScript, I don't know what Ajax is exactly, it would help if you showed me some code that would work with what I am asking to do. Thanks!

Comment: +1 very clean sum up on your site :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple PHP/AJAX example:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: I appreciate the link :D but I am not advanced in js and I don't exactly understand that example, can u just show me the example that will work with this?

Comment: W3schools is not a recommended resource. See http://w3fools.com as to why

Answer (score 0):

No because PHP is server side scripting while JS is client side

Comment: Can you please show me something that will get this to work as I am experienced in PHP but I am far from experienced in JavaScript

Comment: Are you trying to dump the PHP variable into a JS variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You just try the echo to get the specific server value you want instead of using the var_dump